# How to queue requests when underlying framework does not support queueing?

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, notifications, queue, nsoperation

I feel my question is really n00b; apologies if I don't word it clearly :/

In my project I'm using a 3rd party framework that fetches some data for me using asynchronous `NSURLRequests` (RESTful API). 
When the data is received and ready, delegate function `didReceiveResponse` is called. On error case `didFailWithError` is called.

The problem is: framework cannot queue requests, so if I call request methods sequentially I only receive the response for the last request issued.

Now the issue is that I can't change framework's code. Given this is there any way of having a workaround for this problem? Something like: for a set of requests the *n+1* request is not issued until request *n* is finished (either `didReceiveResponse` or `didFailWithError` was called); additionally, when the last request in a set is finished, I get a sort of notification. Ideally, the solution should by supported work for both iOS3 and iOS4.

Comment: @deanWombourne: the framework is not publicly available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your only option is to control the method by which you *start* the requests. To that end, I would abstract the idea of a desired-request into an object or factory of its own: call it `Command`, or `SingleRequestFactory`, or whatever. Hold these objects in an array, and when you receive a `didReceiveResponse` or `didFailWithError`, dequeue the next `Command` and use it to construct the next request, which you pass along to your third-party framework. If you get a `didReceiveResponse` or `didFailWithError` and the queue is empty, post your notification.

It'd probably be best to create an object that does all of this logic on its own, so that your viewcontrollers/whatever is throwing out these requests can just tell the object to queue a `Command` without holding the queue itself.

Comment: I was thinking about something similar but you've shaped the idea nicely so I can translate it into code :) Thanks!

Comment: follow up question: I'm doing things as you suggested and get a crash in UI. In `viewDidLoad` I start my process, so 1st request is sent (asynchronous `NSURLRequest`), I get my `didReceiveResponse` and `didFailWithError` and adjust queue accordingly for next requests. However,right after starting the process, `viewWillAppear` is called and I update the `UIWebView` there with `loadHTMString`. In effect I see a blank screen instead of my web view and a crash if I touch the screen. Strangely, when I don't start that the process, everything is fine. Am I doing sth wrong for `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: ok, got it :) Being overzealous memory citizen is such an own goal ;)