# offline support for queueing AFNetworking requests and saving to disk?

Tags: objective-c, ios, offline, afnetworking

I'm using `AFNetworking` in a project and want any requests issued by the client to be requeued on failure and saved to disk if the app is terminated in order to guarantee that the request will eventually succeed (or at least reach the server). Originally I [wrote my own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5018860/463892) solution but it's become a little cumbersome and I was wondering if AFNetworking has built this in (I'm on an older version) or if anyone has open-sourced their own solution. I've considered [IPOfflineQueue](https://github.com/marcoarment/IPOfflineQueue) as a solution here but I'm a little wary of its "extremely alpha" label and would prefer something a little more vetted. Anyone know of anything out there that address this?

Comment: Had the same problem here, I created a new Class that implements NSCoding, and persisted some vars from NSURLRequest such as httpMethod, httpBody, URL. When applicationDidEnterBackground:, I serialize my queue. On applicationDidBecomeActive: I convert my structure to a NSOperationQueue filled with my persisted "NSURLRequests"

Comment: I've done something similar with CoreData. I might post it up on github once I'm finished working on the project I developed it for.